# Monitor count of downloads of app from BlackBerry App World

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I was wondering whether it is possible to monitor how many people are downloading my Blackberry app from the online store. Is there a developer/admin login to access this kind of data? I have a login for the vendor portal on BlackBerry App World but I dont see any such option there. Can anyone please help with regards to this topic?

I have tried the following:

In my vendor account, there is an option for "Download Reports" with which I have generated a chart report of the "Total Downloads" between specific dates. I am looking for a more detailed statistical version (Excel) as the chart is not as clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get the exact report required. In order to generate a statistical report of the number of downloads of a BlackBerry App from the online store, we can log in to our account (vendor account) and go to "Manage Reports". In it there is an option for "Schedule Reports". Inside "Schedule Reports", select the application for which you need the count of downloads and select a start date and end date. The report can be sorted by:

1. Date only
2. Product, then Date
3. Carrier, then Date
4. Country, then Date
5. Device, then Date

The report is detailed and can easily be downloaded both from "Manage Reports" as well as "Download Reports". The .csv file can be viewed in excel and can later be saved in .xls format as well.

Comment: Just for bookkeeping, you can **accept** your own answer, so people know the problem has been solved.